# Android Studio formats Dart code differently than the dart format tool

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, formatting, code-formatting

Android Studio settings in `Editor -> Code Style -> Dart` state that:

> Code is formatted using the [dart format](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-format) tool included with the Dart SDK. See [FAQ](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ).

But in some cases, it seems to be behave differently than running `dart format .` in the terminal or when using VSCode to format the file.

Take this file for example:

```dart
abstract class Address {
  String? get street;
  int? get postalCode;
  String? get city;
}
```

If I format this file with `dart format` manually, then nothing changes, meaning it is "correctly" formatted.
If I format it with `CTRL + ALT + L` in Android Studio, then this is the output:

```dart
abstract class Address {
  String? get street;

  int? get postalCode;

  String? get city;
}
```

What is going on? Can this be prevented?

Sidenote: I'm on Dart 2.19.5.

Comment: Found a related issue, which explains it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55062/IntelliJ-formatter-is-different-from-dart-format
I think this could only be resolved, if I could turn off that internal formatter.

Answer (score 1):

After Edit:
I have a mac so i'm not sure how the settings are like on windows, but you may need to change the shortkey because there is "Format Code" and "Format Code with 'dart format'".
Ctrl + Alt + L is by default set to "Format Code". You can change it to "Format Code with 'dart format' at

```
Settings > Keymap > Main Menu > Code > Format Code with 'dart format'
```

[image]

--------Below is before edit----------

Android studio has its own Dart plugin which is abit different to the dart sdk that you install locally on your computer, depending on their versions too. So if you use the android studio shortkey, it will use the Dart plugin of your android studio instead of your local dart sdk.

You can try changing that by going to `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Dart` settings and change the path to the dart sdk that is installed locally in your computer. See if that works. The path should be something like `${name}/Developer/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk`

Comment: When I enabled the flutter plugin and entered the path to my flutter sdk, the dart path was automatically inserted too. So this path is already the one I have configured..

Comment: Your welcome. Also as an alternative, you can switch on automatic reformat on save. That way all you have to do is ctrl + s to save your project, and it will automatically reformat the code for you. You can switch that on under Languages & Frameworks > Flutter then under Editor turn on "Format code on save"