# How do I fix Android Studio's dart formatting?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Android Studio's dart formatting adds an extra newline above functions.

The `dart format` command doesn't do this, and nor does VSCode.

Is there a way to configure Android Studio to stop doing this to be consistent with `dart format`? I want to keep reformat on save on.

Tried configuring on Android Studio but there is no way to configure the dart formatting.

There is a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75922917/android-studio-formats-dart-code-differently-than-the-dart-format-tool), but it doesn't provide any solutions.